# Format Chainlink AggregatorV3Interface 'answer' to USD?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, ethereum, chainlink

From the docs, AggregatorV3Interface returns..

```
Return Values
roundId: The round ID.
answer: The price.
startedAt: Timestamp of when the round started.
updatedAt: Timestamp of when the round was updated.
answeredInRound: The round ID of the round in which the answer
was computed.
```

Also it is stated that `answer` is an int256.

I'm getting back the value `120160203575`.

which is the USD as unit8.

How do you format this unit8 into a USD formatted number? (e.g. $1201.00)..formatted with decimal and chopping off the unneeded decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Chainlink can return `decimals` along with the answer.

```
 function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int, uint8) {
    (
      uint80 roundID,
      int price,
      uint startedAt,
      uint timeStamp,
      uint80 answeredInRound
  ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();

    uint8 decimals = priceFeed.decimals();
    return (price, decimals);
  }
```